# Extract domain to a constant from $ref

Tags: swagger, openapi

In swagger/openapi you can define a URL reference to another document, like this:

```
$ref: 'http://example.com/path/to/my/resource'
```

But I'm not a big fan of the idea of having several times the domain replicated in the yaml. 
Are there any way to extract like a constant with a part of the URL? I'd like to do something like this:

```
myDomain: 'http://example.com/path/to'
...
$ref: '${myDomain}/my/resource
```